# Issue with Vulkan installation and HD Graphics 4000

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, vulkan

I've been a long time away from Ubuntu, but I decided to come back with 18.04 build. Everything is great on my laptop. And I read that it comes with driver for Intel Graphics HD 4000 so nothing that I needed to do about the driver, right? If not please correct me.
But I use this laptop for gaming, like Dota 2, and it uses Vulkan. I tried to install vulkan using padoka ppa, and then I did `sudo apt upgrade libglapi-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri vulkan-utils` and even create the symlink for the `libvulkan_intel.so`. But when I type `vulkaninfo` it returns:

```
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70

Cannot create Vulkan instance.
/build/vulkan-Kbdbga/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:768: failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

Did I miss anything? Or isn't really compatible with my GPU?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install vulkan driver

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```